# Caffe and Tensorflow on a Dell 7559 with nvidia optimus technology

Tags: gpu, tensorflow, nvidia, caffe, optimus

I bought a dell 7559 laptop for deep learning. I got ubuntu 16.04 installed on it but I am having trouble getting caffe and tensorflow on it. The laptop used Nvidia Optimus technology to switch between gpu and cpu to save battery usage. I checked the bios to see if I can set it to use only gpu but there is no option for it. Using bumblebee or nvidia-prime didnt work either. I now have ubuntu 16 with mate desktop environment it is preventing from getting the black screen but didnt help with the cuda issue. I was able to install the drivers and cuda but when I build caffe and tensorflow they fail saying that it didnt detect a gpu. And I wasnt able to install opengl. I tried using several versions of nvidia drivers but it didnt help. Any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bumblebee can enable you to run Caffe/Tensorflow in GPU mode. More generally, it also allows you to run other CUDA programs on a laptop with Optimus technology .

When you have installed Bumblebee correctly (tutorial: [Bumblebee Wiki for Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) ), you can invoke the Caffe binary by pepending `optirun` before the caffe binary. So it goes like the following:

```
optirun ../../caffe-master/build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver.prototxt
```

This works for the NVidia DIGITS server as well:

```
optirun ./digits-devserver
```

In addition, Bumblebee also works on my dual-graphics desktop PC (Intel HD 4600 + GTX 750 Ti) as well. The display on my PC is driven by the Intel HD 4600 through the HDMI port on the motherboard. The NVidia GTX 750 Ti is only used for CUDA programs.

In fact, for my desktop PC, the "nvidia-prime" (it's actually invoked through the command line program `prime-select`) is used to choose the GPU that drives the desktop. I have the integrated GPU connect to the display with the HDMI port and the NVidia GPU through a DisplayPort. Currently, the DisplayPort is inactive. The display signal comes from the HDMI port.

As far as I understand, PRIME does so by modifying `/etc/X11/Xorg.conf` to make either the Intel integrated GPU or the NVidia GPU the current display adapter available to X. I think the PRIME settings only makes sense when both GPUs are connected to some display, which means there need not be an Optimus link between the two GPUs like in a laptop (or, for a laptop with a Mux such as Dell Precision M4600, the Optimus is disabled in BIOS).

More information about the Display Mux and Optimus may be found here: [Using the NVIDIA Driver with Optimus Laptops](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/optimus.html)

Hope this helps!